# Reversing a Dict

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am currently trying to make a function which reverses a dict's keys and values. I was looking online and came across this:

```
def reverse(d):
    return dict([(v, k) for k, v in d.iteritems()])
```

My problem is that I'm not sure what this means. I understand the idea of a for loop on the single line but I'm not sure how the (v, k) for k, v leads to the keys and values being reversed. Could someone please offer me a hand. (I did search for this, both online and on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything.)

Comment: I'd avoid the use of the word "reverse", as that implies order.  What you're doing is a [transposition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpose) of your keys and values here.

Comment: What are you going to do if your values aren't unique?

Answer (score 4):

`for k, v in d.iteritems()` is each `key k` and `value v` so reversing v and k with `(v, k)` makes the old value the key and the old key the new value

```
In [7]: d = {1:10,2:20}

In [8]: d.items()
Out[8]: dict_items([(1, 10), (2, 20)]) # tuples of key and value

 In [1]: d = {1:10,2:20}

In [2]: for k,v in d.iteritems():
           print k,v
   ...:     
1 10 # 1 is the key 10 is the value
2 20
In [3]: new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()} # swap key for value and value for key

In [4]: new_d
Out[4]: {10: 1, 20: 2}
```

Two problems you may encounter are duplicate values or values that are not hashable so they cannot be used as keys like lists, sets etc...

```
In [5]: d = {1:2,2:2}

In [6]: new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}

In [7]: new_d
Out[7]: {2: 2} # now only one key and value in the dict

In [8]: d = {1:2,2:[2]}

In [9]: new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-46a3901ce850> in <module>()
----> 1 new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}

<ipython-input-9-46a3901ce850> in <dictcomp>((k, v))
----> 1 new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

`dict([(v, k) for k, v in d.iteritems()])` will have the same output as `{v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}`, the main difference is the former is also compatible with python < 2.7.

If you were using python < 2.7 there is no need to use a list you can just use a generator expression:

```
dict((v, k) for k, v in d.iteritems())
```

Comment: @GBA13: If this answer solved your question, you should consider selecting it as the "selected answer" (the green tick to the left of the answer). It'll help people who find this question in the future, it'll give you rep., it'll give PadraicCunningham rep., it'll encourage other people answer your questions in the future (OPs who systematically don't choose answers are not very well... perceived ) Win Win!! (for further reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 )

Answer (score 1):

the dict constructor can receive an iterable of key/value pairs to create a dictionary, so this code is saying "grab the key/value pairs from this dictionary d and create a new dictionary where the values of d are now the keys and the keys of d become the values"

That is why that the (v,k) are reversed, if you did NOT reverse them, like this

```
 def reverse(d):
    return dict([(k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems()])
```

you would get an identical dictionary back.

also note that in python 2.7 and later you can actually use the even more compact:

```
{v:k for k,v in d.items()}
```

Which reads more intuitively (at least to me) because it looks more like a list comprehension, only it creates a dict.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so when you call `iteritems()` on a dict, it gives you a `(key, value)` tuple for each item in your dictionary:

```
for item in d.iteritems():
    print(item)
```

Then you can assign each item in the tuple to a separate variable using Python's
tuple unpacking syntax:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
print(a)  # 1
print(b)  # 2
```

And if you pass a list of tuples to `dict()`, it treats them as a list
of `(key, value)` items:

```
eg_dict = dict([(a, 4), (b, 6)])
print(eg_dict)
```

Finally, the example you posted makes use of Python's list comprehension
syntax:

```
item_list = ['item' + str(n) for n in range(1, 6)]
print(item_list)
```

To understand the code snippet you've posted, you just need to be
familiar with these Python idioms. If you haven't seen *any*
of these techniques before then it's a fairly dense burst
of new information to get your head around.